# view a stream PipelineDB like a log

Tags: docker, pipelinedb

I am new to pipelineDB and i'm trying to debug stuff around. 
I am using the official pipelinedb/pipelinedb docker image for that.

I think it would be helpful if I could view one of the streams in a "tail -f" manner.
Any suggestions on how I could do that or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

The `padhoc` tool will probably help you here. See https://www.pipelinedb.com/blog/pipelinedb-0-8-3. Note that you'll need to set `continuous_queries_adhoc_enabled` to `on` in `pipelinedb.conf`.